# Azure Functions - TCP Persistent

Tags: azure, azure-functions, tcp

I'm looking for a way to scale a Azure Function properly but I have a problem.

I have a set of IoT devices that send data to Azure by HTTP (For this there is a set of Azure Functions that scale automatically)

But now there is a new IoT device that sends the data via TCP/IP Persistent connections and as far as I know this ins't supported by Azure Functions.

Anyone has some ideia on how to implement this?

One option I thought was to have a VM treating the TCP connections and sending the data to a queue so that a function can pull from the queue in a scalable manner.

Thanks in advance, cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your device only communicates via a persistent TCP/IP connection, then you'll need to implement an IoT Gateway. An IoT Gateway basically an app that either runs on-premises or in the cloud, it communicates with 1 or more IoT devices, then the Gateway can connect to and communicate with a service like Azure IoT Hub. From there, you can get your events sent up to Azure IoT Hub, then process those events in the cloud by using something like Azure Stream Analytics to send then to Event Hubs, or Service Bus Queue, as example. Then once in a Queue you can write an Azure Function to be triggered to handle those events as they come int.

There is no way to open a persistent TCP/IP connection to an Azure Function. Azure Functions are Serverless compute, and are built to be Event-Driven in nature and short running. It is recommended that an Azure Function runs for for a maximum duration of less than 5 minutes per execution.

Comment: Interesting - my assumption was Azure Functions were effectively just web apps (they at least _feel_ like them), outwith the IoT Gateway option, would using a standard web app work? Why exactly is it the TCP connection to an Azure Function fails?

Comment: @James Azure Functions are hosted on top of Azure Web Jobs underneath. They feel like a Web App because of this and the App Service infrastructure platform underneath it all. You could probably use Azure Web Jobs in a dedicated App Service Plan to have a persistent TCP connection. However, why do you need a persistent TCP connection? There may be a better way.

Comment: I need to get data down onto an Arduino device and the GSM module I am using has limited support for SSL, the only way I've managed to successfully establish a secure connection is by opening a TCP connection (connecting to the IoT hub). This is fine for getting data off the device but now I need to get data onto it, I've actually tried connecting via TCP to one of my existing Web Apps and actually it didn't work, the connection seems to be closed immediately (which _sounds_ like it could be a cert problem).

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is decoupling from the device protocols; functions can bind to Event Hubs, and you can put your proxies in containers (pretty easy to host and scale those on App Svcs or AKS).

This way the brittle part (the proxies) are easy to test.

Something like fanout.io might work depending on the protocol. If it's MQTT, going Azure IoT Hub may make sense.